# Missing MSDN Documentation on PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER?

Tags: c++

I can't find any documentation on `_IMAGE_DOS_HEADER`/`PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER`/`e_magic`/`IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE`.

I'm trying to understand the usage of this code:

```
pIDH=(PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)buffer;

if(pIDH->e_magic!=IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE)
{
    printf("\nError: Invalid executable image.\n");

    VirtualFree(buffer,0,MEM_RELEASE);
    return -1;
}
```

What is `e_magic` and it's purpose/meaning? Why is there a comparison for `IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE`?

I guess it's probably to ensure that `pIDH` is a real DOS HEADER, but I'd love to see documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Windows program has a DOS stub program, so if you try to execute the program under MS-DOS, it'll typically print out "This program requires Microsoft Windows", or something similar to that.

So, it starts out with an actual DOS executable header and a couple dozen bytes of code/data. Back in the 16-bit days, the linker let you specify the DOS stub program to be used, so if you wanted to be clever, you could (for example) have the DOS stub execute Windows, and pass the name of the executable on that command line, so Windows would run it when it started.

So, this code is just verifying that at least the beginning of the header for the DOS stub executable is present. The `IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE` is undoubtedly just "MZ", though perhaps stored as a 16-bit little-endian integer, to make it easy to compare in a single instruction. A DOS .EXE file is required to start with "MZ" to signify what it is (if it starts with something else, the DOS loader will normally presume that it's a .COM file, but the DOS stub has to be a .EXE, not a .COM).

Comment: Thanks for the info. Where did you learn this? Is there any documentation I can reference? I'd need it for more things like `PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS` and `PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER`

Comment: Not sure where I first learned it--probably some paper magazine in the 1980s or so, but I couldn't even guess which one (there were many, back then). MS does have at least some documentation at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/pe-format#ms-dos-stub-image-only

Comment: Also see [Peering Inside the PE: A Tour of the Win32 Portable Executable File Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

it means that the program cannot be run in DSO mode..